# Outlook email attachment files and save in sql

Tags: c#, outlook, casting, com-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to save the Outlook attachment file email and save in sql. I tried this following code and it only saved a numerical values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace RetrieveEmail
{
    public class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application oLk = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._NameSpace olNS = oLk.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            olNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);


            Outlook.Items oItems = oFolderIn.Items;

            foreach (object item in oFolderIn.Items)
            {
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem oMailItem)
                {
                    
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=EmailReply;Integrated Security=True");
                 
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Emails (SenderName, Subject, Body, Attachment) VALUES (@SenderName, @Subject, @Body, @Attachment)", con);
                   
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderName", oMailItem.SenderName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", oMailItem.Subject);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", oMailItem.Body);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment", oMailItem.EnableSharedAttachments); // I tried this code to extract Outlook attachment file email
                    

                    con.Open();
                    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (k != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Record Inserted Succesfully into the Database");

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what saved in my sql, it didn't save the attachment I'm trying to save the attachment file with extension of (.docx .pdf .excel .pptx)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what `EnableSharedAttachments` is, but I doubt it is an attachment.

Comment: I used varbinary(MAX) for attachment data type in sql

Comment: I think MailItem has an Attachments property. You should look there and don't assume any specific number of attachments being present.

Comment: By the way, you should consider moving the connection, command and parameters out of the loop. Just change the parameter values within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the attached file on the disk first. The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for getting the attachment content on the fly at runtime. Use the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path.

Extended MAPI allows reading the attachment bytes on the fly by using the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` property holds the attachment when the value of the `PR_ATTACH_METHOD` property is `ATTACH_BY_VALUE`, which is the usual attachment method and the only one required to be supported. You may consider using any third-party wrapper around Extended MAPI such as Redemption for getting the binary data of attached files.